# Interceptar Exception

Tags: java, jsf, exceção, demoiselle

Estou utilizando o Demoiselle em minha aplicação, porem ele não vem se comportando muito bem em um aspecto.
Em uma associação entre duas ou mais entidades, ao deletar é lançado uma exceção. Com o tratamento de exceções disponível no Demoiselle, criei um metodo para capturar esta exceção, mas não estamos conseguindo capturá-la.

Segue código de exemplo.

```
@Entity
public class Bookmark implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String description;
    @Column
    private String link;
```

E a classe Cliente:

```
@Entity
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "bookmark_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Bookmark bookmark;
```

Através disso, podemos ver que o Cliente possui uma associação de muitos para um com o Bookmark.
Portanto, ao cadastrar um cliente eu devo adicionar um bookmark a ele.
O problema ocorre ao excluir um bookmar que possui referência em um cliente.
Ele me retorna o seguinte erro.

> Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing
>   the transaction   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:92)     at
>   br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.transaction.JPATransaction.commit(JPATransaction.java:121)
>     ... 60 more Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:80)
>     ... 61 more Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`db_estacionamento`.`cliente`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_ht5q4yqv47muisi25vq14yw2u` FOREIGN KEY (`bookmark_id`) REFERENCES
>   `bookmark` (`id`))

Para tentar tratar esse erro, na classe BookmarkEditMB eu criei um método para capturar esta exceção. Mas, **especificadamente** este caso, não é possível capturá-la.

```
@ViewController
@PreviousView("/bookmark_list.xhtml")
public class BookmarkEditMB extends AbstractEditPageBean<Bookmark, Long> {

    @ExceptionHandler
    public void tratador(ConstraintViolationException cause) {
        messageContext.add("Estou tentando tratar a exceção aqui.", SeverityType.WARN);
    }
}
```

Já tentei capturar todos os tipos de exceção que ocorrem ao deletar, mas nenhum deles é capturado pelo método. Tentei capturar outros tipos de exceção e ela é capturada perfeitamente. **Neste caso específico (ao deletar) não consigo capturá-la.**

Nesta página do manual do Demoiselle explica como utilizar o@ ExceptionHandler: http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/framework/reference/2.4.2/html/excecao.html#d0e996

Abaixo segue um link para download de uma aplicação de exemplo:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2mw7Hlip92vQUhhX2NRWWFrNm8/view?usp=sharing

Desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Ola... Pior que comentamos isso hoje, ainda não achamos uma solução!

Answer (score 1):

Olá. Também passo pelo mesmo problema. O que segue **não é uma resposta**, é apenas a solução de contorno que eu encontrei e estou usando por enquanto. Só consegui com o velho try-catch...

No BusinessController:

```java
@Override
public void delete (Long id) {
    try {
        efetivaDelete(id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MeuErroException("msg..."); //esse eu consigo pegar no MB
    }
}

@Transactional
private void efetivaDelete(Long id) {
    getDelegate().delete(id);
}
```

Assim consegui pegar a minha exceção no @ExceptionHandler do MB.

Comment: Bom dia, não funcionou isso! inclusive o método delete não suporta esta Exceção.

Answer (score 1):

Enfrentamos o mesmo problema, a `ConstraintViolationException` é encapsulada em `TransactionException`. Então optei pela seguinte solução:

```
@ExceptionHandler
public void tratarErroInesperado(RuntimeException e) throws IOException {
    if (tratarConstraintViolationException(e)) {
        return;
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

private boolean tratarConstraintViolationException(Exception e) {
    Throwable cause = e;
    while (cause != null) {
        if (cause instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
            for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : cve.getConstraintViolations()) {
                messageContext.add(violation.getMessage(), SeverityType.ERROR);
            }
            return true;
        }
        cause = cause.equals(cause.getCause()) ? null : cause.getCause();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao interceptar a `exception` faça a manipulação pelo tipo `ValidationException`, que é a exception 'pai' desta que manipulou.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele.

Comment: Melhorou, @ramaral ?

Comment: Agora já parece uma resposta!

Comment: obrigado, é que sou novo aqui ainda, já uso a muito tempo mas sou cadastrado a pouco.

Comment: Ola. Só para não ficar sem resposta, também testamos isso e não funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

Apesar de ser apenas um *chute*, acredito que o seguinte deveria funcionar:

```
@ViewController
@PreviousView("/bookmark_list.xhtml")
public class BookmarkEditMB extends AbstractEditPageBean<Bookmark, Long> {

    @ExceptionHandler
    public void tratador(RollbackException cause) {
        messageContext.add("Estou tentando tratar a exceção RollbackException aqui.", SeverityType.WARN);
        if (cause.getCause() != null) {
            throw cause.getCause();
        }
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    public void tratador(PersistenceException cause) {
        messageContext.add("Estou tentando tratar a exceção PersistenceException aqui.", SeverityType.WARN);
        if (cause.getCause() != null) {
            throw cause.getCause();
        }
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    public void tratador(ConstraintViolationException cause) {
        messageContext.add("Estou tentando tratar a exceção ConstraintViolationException aqui.", SeverityType.WARN);
    }
}
```

Meu *chute* baseia-se na ideia de que provavelmente a exceção `ConstraintViolationException` está sendo lançada fora do escopo do interceptador, ao passo que provavelmente a exceção `RollbackException` (e talvez `PersistenceException` também) já estão dentro do escopo, sendo possíveis de serem interceptadas. Como as exceções estão encapsuladas em cadeia. Então, para enxergá-las no nível desejado, basta desencapsular uma a uma.

Comment: Bom dia. Acabei de realizar o teste, mas não funciona! Infelizmente não consegui pegar a exceção!